# Gson: Serialization from JSON to java object whit inner object list

Tags: serialization

I have :

```
public class RequisicionImpresion {


private List<Files> archivos;

private String impresora;

... // getter & setters

}


    public class FileDto {

private String  lote;

private Long    idDoc;

private String  nombre;

private String  ruta;

//Getter & setters

}
```

I'm getting the JSON:

```
{"archivos":[{"lote":"JULIO_20160125_001","idDoc":9038,"nombre":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf","ruta":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf"},
        {"lote":"JULIO_20160125_001","idDoc":9185,"nombre":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf","ruta":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf"},
        {"lote":"JULIO_20160125_001","idDoc":9184,"nombre":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf","ruta":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf"},
        {"lote":"JULIO_20160125_001","idDoc":9039,"nombre":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf","ruta":"/siat/anexo/pruebas/Anexo 1.pdf"}],
        "impresora":"00000061677"}
```

I need serialize for get object RequisionImpresion with filled values. I don't know how to navigate for the element 'archivos' and also get the other elements.

I have done with:

```
nuevaRequsicionImpresion = jsonUtil.convertJsonToObject(json);
```

where:

```
JsonUtil.java 

...
public final T convertJsonToObject(final String json) {
        T valor = null;

        if (json != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            valor = (T) gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<T>() {
            } .getType());
        }

        return valor;
    }

...
```

However I'm getting the exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

Answer (score 0):

In my utility class JsonUtil I've updated the method:

```
...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final T convertJsonToObject(final String json, final T clase) {
        T valor = null;

        if (json != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            valor = (T) gson.fromJson(json, clase.getClass());
        }

        return valor;
    }

...
```